# ServiceStack ORMLite SQLite implementation fails on Mac M1

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-core, apple-m1, ormlite-servicestack

We use SQLite in-memory databases in our dotnet codebase for integration testing our repository layer with ORMLite. When I try to run a test on Mac I get this error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException
Unable to load shared library 'SQLite.Interop.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libSQLite.Interop.dll, 0x0001): tried: 'libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file), '/Users/aaron/Projects/joinder/DASH/Test/ClientSiteData.Tests/bin/Debug/net6.0/libSQLite.Interop.dll' (no such file)
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(SQLiteConfigOpsEnum op)
```

Is there a way to get this working on Mac so I don't have to revert to my Windows machine every time I need to run tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try installing one of the other [OrmLite.SQLite packages](https://docs.servicestack.net/ormlite/installation#sqlite), e.g. to use the [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/) ADO.NET Provider use:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite.Data" Version="6.*" />
```

Comment: Same result. Do I need to remove ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite?

Comment: @devlord yes, you should only have 1 SQLite package installed, also delete the bin/ and obj/ folders before installing the new package to ensure a clean build